# Printing bitcoin address transactions using blockchain API

Tags: php, arrays, api, bitcoin, blockchain

I'm building a php site and need some of the functionality provided by the blockchain API (https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php)

I'm trying to print out an overview of all transactions done to a specific address, but no success so far.

I've gathered the info of the address, but the transactions are stored in an array (as written in the documentations), and can't get them out.

```
$limit = 50;
$offset = 0;
$address = "xxx";
$address_info = $Blockchain->Explorer->getAddress($address, $limit, $offset);
echo $address_info->n_tx; //just as a test, this works

$transactions = $address_info->transactions; //no error here
echo $transactions->version;
```

The last line of code throws this error: "Trying to get property of non-object". echo $transactions[0] also doesn't work.

The github page doesn't feature any examples of printing out transactions.

The var_dump function of $transactions produces this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Blockchain\Explorer\Transaction)[11]
      public 'double_spend' => boolean false
      public 'block_height' => int 382334
      public 'time' => int 1446833376
      public 'lock_time' => int 0
      public 'relayed_by' => string '192.99.2.32' (length=11)
      public 'hash' => string 'd9f625afe46ea8bbe9dc74484cefbcb15fbd6887a1bc619b44161114b78ab038' (length=64)
      public 'tx_index' => int 109866616
      public 'version' => int 1
      public 'size' => int 374
      public 'inputs' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Blockchain\Explorer\Input)[12]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(Blockchain\Explorer\Input)[13]
              ...
      public 'outputs' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Blockchain\Explorer\Output)[14]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(Blockchain\Explorer\Output)[15]
              ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `var_dump( $transactions )` or `print_r( $transactions )` to see what it contains

Comment: Thanks!, I've tried that before and this prints the whole array, but i'd like to process the array contents within separate variables.

The var_dump results in this:

`array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Blockchain\Explorer\Transaction)[11]
      public 'double_spend' => boolean false
      public 'block_height' => int 382334
      public 'time' => int 1446833376
      public 'lock_time' => int 0
      public 'relayed_by' => string '192.99.2.32' (length=11)
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$transactions` is a PHP array, not an object. You can access the version of the first object in the array using `$transactions[0]->version`, or iterate through the array using something like `foreach ($transaction in $transactions) { ... }`.